# need to filter which ever the region is selected in cloudmapper using Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web

Initially, cloudmap.js will be loaded and you can find the file under js. towards the left top corner, there is a button "Delete" which will delete the selected region but my requirement is to show the selected region.
[image]

Here is the existing code

```
function hideSelectedNodes() {
    var actions = [];
    var nodesToHide = cy.$(":selected").add(cy.$(":selected").nodes().descendants());
    var nodesWithHiddenNeighbor = cy.edges(":hidden").connectedNodes().intersection(nodesToHide);
    actions.push({ name: "thinBorder", param: nodesWithHiddenNeighbor });
    actions.push({ name: "hide", param: nodesToHide });
    nodesWithHiddenNeighbor = nodesToHide.neighborhood(":visible")
        .nodes().difference(nodesToHide).difference(cy.nodes("[thickBorder]"));
    actions.push({ name: "thickenBorder", param: nodesWithHiddenNeighbor });
    cy.undoRedo().do("batch", actions);
}
```

I have tried lot of things like ":unselected" name:"show".. but did not work. please help we with this issue.

here is the link (https://github.com/duo-labs/cloudmapper)

here is the source code (https://github.com/duo-labs/cloudmapper/tree/master/web)

Comment: What are you trying to do here exactly? Do you want to hide the seleced regions (like the provided code suggests) or do you want to show/expand the selected regions (as you stated in the second line of your question)?

Comment: show the selected regions

Comment: There is literally a button for that in the [CloudMapper Example](https://duo-labs.github.io/cloudmapper/) => You just need to select the elements and click on the plus in the navbar. If you want to implement that logic, just copy whatever the example does at that point

Comment: From the github page, you can view the expand method here: [see expandRecursively](https://github.com/duo-labs/cloudmapper/blob/master/web/js/cloudmap.js)